# hook_menu how to render the layout

Tags: routes

```
function test_menu()
{

    $items['test'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'test_test',
    'title' => 'test',
    'menu_name' => 'navigation',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access callback' => true
    );

    return $items;
}

function test_test()
{
    echo 555;
}
```

when I access to url /test, i see '555', but how to render the layout itself and in the content of the page show '555'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change "echo 555;" to "return 555;"

Comment: You did that. That's fine :)

Comment: hmmm... i've tried it but i see a blank page, without 555

Comment: oh. You can't return a number for that page. It should be return "555";